# Agent is not leaving the Assembler block in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Agent is not leaving the assembler block while the model keeps runing with out showing any error. The image of Assembler properties is given below.

[image]

**When I run the model, I act like this all the time.**

[image]

Moreover, when I limited the number of arrivals to one for the sources, then it worked just fine.Kindly let me know what I am missing and how to solve this issue.

Comment: do you have 4 unit resources available?

Comment: yeah, likely you are not having those resources needed to assemble

Comment: yes, that was exactly the problem.